# Fitting a student t distribution in R using fitdistr() yields error "non-finite finite-difference value"

Tags: r

Reproducable example which will give the mentioned error code every time is:
(Note that even without set.seed, the error comes up every time)

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(seed = 1)
data<-rnorm(n = 10000,mean = 0.0002,sd = 0.001)
fitdistr(x = data,densfun = "t")
```

The error message is:

```
Error in stats::optim(x = c(-0.000426453810742332,       0.000383643324222082,  : 
non-finite finite-difference value [2]
In addition: Warning message:
In log(s) : NaNs produced
```

The problem is the "non-finite finite-difference value". Fitdistr does not give me a result.

My knowledge: 
I researched and apparently this could mean that a parameter is negative during the iteration. And that the solution could be to provide a better or at least different starting value. But I could not figure out how to do this and I am not sure if this is the issue.

MY QUESTION:
a) Why do I get this error message 
and 
b)how can I fix it in R, so that I can fit the student-t distribution to my normally distributed data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: I added an example. Is this ok?

Comment: That's great, thanks. We'll migrate this shortly.